# send a file to other teams user using command line

Tags: command-line, microsoft-teams

I'd like to be able to send programatically a file to another user or group, preferably with an text message, is there a command that would allow me to do that ?

My input :

**situation 1**

- user : "john.doe@foo.com"
- file : "C://this/that/here.csv"
- message : "Hi John, here's a csv"

**situation 2**

- group: "my team chat"
- file : "C://this/that/here.csv"
- message : "Hi all, here's a csv"

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using Team graph api's. Graph exposes two resource for working with files, please check the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/onedrive?view=graph-rest-1.0). You can not send files directly but you can save it in oneDrive and share the location. You can handle message by sending message card or as activity.